# DocumentClass options - ex

Tags: fontsize, document-classes, options

I have a LaTeX file with the following line:

```
\documentclass[1.5ex]{report}
```

Can I confirm that the options set is to set the x height of the main body font to 1.5mm? (as an aside does anyone know what size that would be in pt/Word?)

Comment: If I create a small MWE, such as `\documentclass[1.5ex]{report}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}` and compile it, I end up with the following warning: "Unused global option(s):[1.5ex]." Adding `1.5ex` as an option to the `report` class has no effect and you end up with the default font size, which is `10pt`.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed this myself!

Comment: Maybe there's a document class or LaTeX package out there that recognizes and acts on the option `1.5ex` -- whatever this action may be. However, as you've already discovered, `1.5ex` is *not* an option defined in the main LaTeX document classes such as `article`, `report`, and `book`. Therefore, the `1.5ex` option should in no way be interpreted as causing the putative behavior of "set[ting] the x height of the main body font to 1.5mm" if the `report` document class is in use.

Comment: If you want Word like font sizes, use big point (bp) instead of pt. This is supported by the KOMA-Script classes (use the class option `fontsize=12bp`)